Unable to filter by request URL in chrome extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension that will look for the response of a url that contains "bounds" . The full URL is:
https://www.land.com/api/0/United-States/all-land/zoom-12/bounds-38.487397840020606-n98.67873224975584-38.67660627098903-n98.39205775024412/?sk=_cljFjdpxQz^utWzgJnbFwy@|`U_mIwnC

I'm starting with a sanity check to make sure that I am selecting the right URL:
function handleRequestFinished(request) {
  if (
    request.request.url.includes("bounds") &&
    request.request.url.includes("land")
  ) {
    console.log("---------------------------------");
    console.log(request.request.url);
    console.log("request");
    console.log("---------------------------------");
  }
}

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(handleRequestFinished);
However I am getting all kinds of urls printed to the console which do not appear to have either of the conditions met. What am I doing wrong?

Can you confirm if those long urls shortened with ellipsis are not containing the words?

I think if you click on the ... in the URL it will expand it to show the complete URL, and your keywords are in there somewhere.
